# Import tsx into jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tsx

I have a component ChartContainer.tsx and I want to import this component into index.jsx like this

ChartContainer.tsx

```
export class ChartContainer
```

index.jsx

```
import ChartContainer from './ChartContainer'
```

But I got an error

> Module not found: Can't resolve

Please help me to use tsx in jsx file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you using webpack ? give more info ! Thats not a salvageable question at all...

Comment: Actually I have 2 projects. One I use react-redux including js and jsx files. Another uses tsx files. Then I want to import only 1 component from the second project that used tsx file into first project.

Comment: You'll need something like webpack to handle the ts files from js. Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: make sure you have loaded babel presets,plugins and webpack

Comment: I've used yo create-redux-app like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-create-redux-app